# combine async and sync function results in an elegant way

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I check a javascript object against several check functions (some are synchronous and some are asynchronous functions). Is there a way to combine the function results in a more elegant way? My approach was to combine all synchronous functions results in `isValid` and push all async function results to an array `pendingPromises`.
After iterating over all check functions, i resolve all pendingPromises, reduce the result and combine it with the result of the synchronous functions.
Thanks in advance.

```
const checks = {
  checkA(data) { return true; },
  checkB(data) { return true; },
  async checkC(data) { return false; },
  async checkD(data) { return true; }
};

async function checkAll(data) {
  const pendingPromises = [];
  let isValid = true;

  // get all check functions
  const checkFunctions = Object.keys(checks)
    .filter((prop) => prop.startsWith('check'))
    .map((checkFunction) => checks[checkFunction]);
  
  // iterate over all check functions
  for (const checkFunction of checkFunctions) {
    if (checkFunction[Symbol.toStringTag] === 'AsyncFunction') {
      // async
      pendingPromises.push(checkFunction(data));
    } else {
      // sync
      isValid = isValid && checkFunction(data);
    }
  }

  try {
    const promiseResults = await Promise.all(pendingPromises);
    const res = promiseResults.reduce((acc, checkResult) => acc && checkResult, true);
    // return the combined result
    return res && isValid;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"more elegant way"_? What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: I have no idea, if this is the recommended way to go or not. This is a just a solution i came up with.

Comment: You can await synchronous functions, so unless you're trying to parallelize things, you can just do `isValid = isValid && await checkFunction(data)`. Your way is fine though, probably better.

Comment: It looks good to me.  If I were to make minor change to improve I would use Array.every() instead of Array.reduce() in order to check all true.  But it is really off the topic here.  :-)

Comment: Is it required to run all checks eagerly? Why not stop on a first failure? In case of async functions this could even consists in running them in a sequence but still, return false upon first failure.

Comment: @WiktorZychla you are absolutely right, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> if (checkFunction[Symbol.toStringTag] === 'AsyncFunction') {
> ```

Don't do that. There might be functions that are not marked as `async` that still return promises. Also this doesn't work well with transpilers.

> Is there a way to combine the function results in a more elegant way?

Yes, just pass all the values to `Promise.all`. It doesn't care whether the array elements are promises or plain values, it just does `Promise.resolve` them.

So you can simplify your code to

```
async function checkAll(data) {
  const results = await Promise.all(
    Object.keys(checks)
    .filter(prop => prop.startsWith('check'))
    .map(prop => checks[prop](data))
  );
  return results.every(Boolean);
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

If you running any async function you can just assume that all functions/values are async:

```
const checks = {
  checkA(data) { return true; },
  checkB(data) { return false; },
  async checkC(data) { return true; },
  async checkD(data) { return true; }
};

async function checkAll(data) {
  const pendingPromises = [];
  let isValid = true;

  // get all check functions
  const checkFunctions = Object.keys(checks)
    .filter((prop) => prop.startsWith('check'))
    .map((checkFunction) => checks[checkFunction]);
  
  // iterate over all check functions
  for (const checkFunction of checkFunctions) {
      pendingPromises.push(await checkFunction(data));
  }

  try {
    const promiseResults = await Promise.all(pendingPromises);
    const res = promiseResults.reduce((acc, checkResult) => acc && checkResult, true);
    // return the combined result
    return res && isValid;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: if you `await` the `checkFunction(data)` in the loop, you don't need `Promise.all` any longer

Comment: not in a synchronous loops.

Comment: Sure does. Your `pendingPromises` array never contains any promises.

Comment: got what you meant now. You're right